# What is the posterior probability of the data given the model used for model averaging with Bayesian Logistic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, bayesian

I am trying to learn about Bayesian Model Averaging using Bayesian Logistic Regression (Genkin, A., Lewis, D. D., & Madigan, D. (2007). Large-scale Bayesian logistic regression for text categorization. Technometrics, 49(3), 291-304.), as found in the Weka data mining tool.

I have two questions—

1. What are the ways in which models are generated using Bayesian Logistic Regression? (are subsets of predictive variables used at a time? are hyperparameters of the priors altered for each model?)
2. What is the posterior probability of the model (weights for model averaging) used? Is it the likelihood of the data and the parameters of the logistic regression? or, is it computed with information theoretic methods like AIC/BIC (I am unfamiliar with this)?

Thank you.